# Is there a way to get mysql returned rows such that it is divisible by 5

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

As we can get specific number of rows from mysql using the LIMIT keyword but that is specific, I want to limit the number of rows returned should be divisible by 5 i.e.

say 27 is the number of rows return by the query then I would like to LIMIT it to 25 as 
25 % 5 = 0.

similarly if total number of results returned are 32 then the LIMIT should be set to 30.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is SO not worth doing.  The whole purpose of being able to limit rows is so that you don't select huge quantities of unnecessary data.  For example, if a table has 20000 rows, and you want to display 20, there's no point in selecting all 20000.  But you're talking about excluding at most 4 rows of data.  It's certainly not worthwhile to select `count(*)` before you start, to see what limit you should use.  Just select all of the data, and discard any unwanted rows within the Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `count(*)` then calculate `LIMIT = count / 5 * 5;`